# Opening app in app store with custom parameters

Tags: ios, app-store

I am trying to have a link on my website that will open the app on the App Store, with some extra parameters, which my app can then use once it is installed.

The sequence would be similar to this:

1. User visits my website and clicks a link to install app on App Store.
2. User is redirected to the app store and installs links
3. App is launched with the extra parameters passed in URL in step 1.

Hopefully it could look something like this:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789?user=foo&page=bar
```

The main reason I would like to do something like this would be so a user can jump right to the same page they were on, and possibly also be logged in.

I did some research on this already, but only found stuff for affiliate linking (which maybe could be used for this) but this doesn't seem like the right option.

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/basic_affiliate_link_guidelines_for_the_phg_network/

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**

It turns out this is called "Deferred Deep Linking", here are some similar threads I've found:

[How to make deferred deep linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352647/how-to-make-deferred-deep-linking)

[Deferred Deep Linking in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855618/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios)

Comment: For anyone looking into this I would take a look at branch.io their services are great!

Answer (score -2):

You can do this scenario with 2 ways

1-) define URL scheme on your iOS app firstly.

- For example, you define "dateApp" as a URL scheme.
- After that, if you write on safari browser this adress "***dateApp://***" your browser should ask you **should this page open on: "DataApp"?** if this app installed on your phone

2-) Firebase Dynamic Links.

- You should implemented related SDK and callback on your app.
- After that you should prepare dynamic link from firebase [dashboard](https://firebase.google.com/)
- You should check this option if you don't want see preview page.
  [image]

**Note**: *firebase dynamic link option is more powerfull. Because if someone not install your app but clicked firebase link, redirecting AppStore. After installation process, if opening app in 2 hours, deeplink url cachted by firebase. So you can route appropriate page.*

Firebase deeplink example for you :)
**https://www.dateapp.com.tr/?page=CampaignDetail&p=78771**

Comment: yes but how do you get this to work with the appstore link? itms-app store

Comment: Which option do you ask the question for? If you ask firebase dynamic link option, I added case url in my post.